# airflow sla_miss_callback function doesn't trigger and doesn't show up in dag details page

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I would like to send alerts via my custom callback function that I'm calling during dag initialization as show below-

`dag = DAG('tutorial', default_args=default_args, schedule_interval=timedelta(days=1), sla_miss_callback=my_sla_miss_cb_func)`

My def signature is as follows-

`def my_sla_miss_cb_func():
        ...custom_logic....`

I've got `sla` attribute for the tasks I would like to monitor and I see that I get SLA MISS emails when I give email_on_failure=True but my_sla_miss_cb_func function doesn't get called/triggered.

Also, sla_miss_callback attribute doesn't show up in `Details` page in airflow UI.

I'm using airflow 1.7.1.3

Comment: The airflow scheduler should [invoke](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py#L476) your callback and [log](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py#L478) any exceptions.
The scheduler also [sends](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/88989200a66291580088188f06a6db503ac823e2/airflow/jobs/scheduler_job.py#L500) an email (which you are receiving) if the task is configured to do so. Do the scheduler logs incidate which code path is executed?

Comment: Have you resolved your problem? I'm having the same one. On the `Sla Misses` page I see SLA miss is detected. But in logs, I see no indications that it tries to trigger my callback.